# PHPStorm 9 keeps deleting my colors folder

Tags: phpstorm

I'm trying to add a new color scheme to PHPStorm, and following the instructions I've found online, it says to create a "colors" folder in `Users/UserName/.WebIde90/config/` every time I restart PHPStorm, the folder gets deleted.

Comment: 1) Your OS 2) Try cloning existing color scheme in IDE and then modify at least one style -- it will create that folder for you. See if it will survive IDE restart. If does -- copy your files there.

Comment: That did it. After saving an edited copy of Darcula, and pasting in the new color scheme I was wanting to save, it made me realize that the file I was trying to use was a `.icl` when it should have been a `.icls`